# Overriding/Wrapping spring beans in java based config multiple times

Tags: java, spring

I have a (web-)application that needs special configurations and/or extensions based on the customer using the application. I call these additions "plugins" and they are auto discovered by classpath scanning when the application starts. For extensions that is incredibly easy. Let's say I want to have a plugin which adds an API that prints "hello world" when the URL /myplugin/greet is called: I just create a `@Controller` annotated class with the according `@RequestMapping`, put this in a `myplugin.jar`, copy that on the classpath and that's it.

Problems come up when I want to change some defaults and especially if I want to do this multiple times. Let's say my core application has a config like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class CoreConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Set<String> availableModules() {
        return Collections.singleton("core");
    }
}
```

Now I have two plugins that don't know about each other (but they do know the CoreConfig), but they both want to add themselves to the list of available modules. How would I do that? If I only had a single plugin that wants to override the module list I could override the existing bean from CoreConfiguration, but with two plugins that becomes a problem. What I *imagine* is something like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class FirstPluginConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Set<String> availableModules(Set<String> availableModules) {
        Set<String> extendedSet = new HashSet<>(availableModules);
        extendedSet.add("FirstPlugin");
        return extendedSet;
    }
}
```

Of course a `SecondPluginConfiguration` would look nearly exactly like this, except that the Set is not extended by "FirstPlugin", but by "SecondPlugin". I tested it to check what would happen and spring will just never call the First/SecondPluginConfiguration "availableModules" methods but it does not show an error either.

Now of course in this case this could easily be solved by using a mutable Set in the CoreConfiguration and then autowiring and extending the set in the other configurations, but for example I also want to be able to add method interceptors to some beans. So for example I might have an interface `CrashLogger` which has a `logCrash(Throwable t)` method and in CoreConfiguration a `ToFileCrashLogger` is created that writes stack traces to files as the name suggests. Now a plugin could say that he also wants to get notified about crashes, for example the plugin wants to ADDITIONALLY send the stacktrace to someone by email. For that matter that plugin could wrap the CrashLogger configured by the CoreConfiguration and fire BOTH. A second plugin could wrap the wrapper again and do something totally different with the stacktrace and still call both of the other CrashLoggers.

The later does sound somewhat like AOP and if I'd just let ALL my beans be proxied (I did not test that) I could autowire them into my plugin configurations, cast them to `org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised` and then add advices that manipulate behaviour. However it does seem like a huge overkill to generate proxies for each and everyone of my beans just so that that plugin can potentially add one or two advices one one or two beans.

Comment: You can inject CoreConfiguration  into FirstPluginConfiguration ?  so now you have a defined order of instantiation at startup and a common place to have your registry (in CoreConfiguration with a method to addPlugin()).  You want `@PostConstruct` on the method to call when the object is instantiated, so availableModule() is always called.  Remove `@Bean` for Set<String> as it make no sense.

Comment: @DarrylMiles: As far as I understand you this means that I can inject beans from CoreConfiguration into my PluginConfigurations to mutate them there. However I do not just want to mutate them. I want to *replace* them (with a new bean wrapping the original one).

Comment: This sounds like what you really want is a filter chain/chain of responsibility.